# Make an array from a class object

Tags: c#

When I make the `seats[] seatArray`, and try to run it, I get an error

> NullReferenceException was unhandled. Object Reference not set to an instance of an object.

I think it's my printinfo function at the end.

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{      
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
       Seats s = new Seats();
        //Seats[] seatArray = new Seats[14]; //HEREEE
        public Form1()
        {

            InitializeComponent();
            listBox2.Items.Add("ROW#   A   B   C   D   E   F");
            listBox2.Items.Add("  1    " + s.PrintInfo);
           // listBox2.Items.Add( seatArray[0].PrintInfo); //HEREEE

            listBox1.Items.Add("Seats Filled:");
            listBox1.Items.Add("Windows Available:");
            listBox1.Items.Add("Regular Meals:");
            listBox1.Items.Add("LowCal Meals:");
            listBox1.Items.Add("Veget Meals:");

        }

        private void listBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string test = listBox2.SelectedItem.ToString(); /
            //string[] div = Regex.Split(test, "     ");
            //textBox2.Text = div[0];
            textBox2.Text = test; //     
        }
    }

    public class Seats // 
    {
        public char A;
        public char B;
        public char C;
        public char D;
        public char E;
        public char F;

        public Seats()
        {
            A = '.';
            B = '.';
            C = '.';
            D = '.';
            E = '.';
            F = '.';
        }

        public char Aa
        {
            set { A = value; }
            get { return A; }
        }
        public char Bb
        {
            set { A = value; }
            get { return A; }
        }
        public char Cc
        {
            set { C = value; }
            get { return C; }
        }
        public char Dd
        {
            set { D = value; }
            get { return D; }
        }
        public char Ee
        {
            set { E = value; }
            get { return E; }
        }
        public char Ff
        {
            set { F = value; }
            get { return F; }
        }


        public string PrintInfo // 
        {
            get { return this.A + "    " + this.B + "    " + this.C + "    " + this.D + "    " + this.E + "    " + this.F; }


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This question is a bit of a mess. What specifically are you asking. I see a mention of a `NullReferenceException` (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) and something about how to display properties in text boxes?

Comment: I've removed irrelevant methods from your code example (blank with nothing in them). Make sure you **only include relevant information in your question**

Answer (score 2):

When an array is created, it is filled with the default value for the given type.  For reference types, the default value is `null`.  You need to add items to the array before you can use them:

```
Seats[] seatArray = new Seats[14]; 
seatArray[0] = new Seat();   // or something like this
public Form1()
{

    InitializeComponent();
    listBox2.Items.Add("ROW#   A   B   C   D   E   F");
    listBox2.Items.Add("  1    " + s.PrintInfo);
    listBox2.Items.Add( seatArray[0].PrintInfo); //HEREEE
```

If you want to create an array of 14 uninitialized seats you can use:

```
Seats[] seatArray = Enumerable.Repeat(new Seat(),14).ToArray();
```